# Sharepoint zones

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to create a new sharepoint application and for some reason the zone dropdown doesn't contain "extranet". Does anyone know how to add zones?

Answer (score 0):

The names of the zones don't mean anything.  You can set them up however you want.  There is no way to add new zones as they are hard wired in the code.  See this [link](http://blog.sharepointalist.com/2009/04/sharepoint-2007-moss-add-url-zone.html)
That being said, there should be an "Extranet" zone as this is one that is hardwired in.

I think it would have been better if MS would have just numbered the zones and let the user name them.